# Why does `int in List[List[int]]` return `False` but `np.int in List[List[int]]` return `True`?

Tags: python, list, numpy

I observed this strange behavior while checking if a number is in a list. If the number is of generic int type, the check failed; but the check went through successfully if the number is of numpy.int64 type. Can anyone explain why? I know I could do better by generating the list `lst=df['A'].values.tolist()` to get a list of integers instead of a list of list. But my question is why the numpy.int64 would work below?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(31, 36)})
print(df)

#     A
# 0  31
# 1  32
# 2  33
# 3  34
# 4  35

lst=df.values.tolist()
print(lst)
# [[31], [32], [33], [34], [35]]

x=31
print(x) # 31
print(type(x)) # <class 'int'>
if x in lst:
    print('Yes')
else:
    print('No')
# prints No!

y=df['A'][0]
print(y)  # 31
print(type(y)) # <class 'numpy.int64'>
if y in lst:
    print('Yes')
else:
    print('No')
# prints Yes
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your list doesn't contain `31`. It contains another list that contains `31`, but it doesn't directly contain `31`.

`thing in lst` works like this:

```
for x in lst:
    if x is thing or x == thing:
        return True
return False
```

When you check whether a regular int is in your list, `x == thing` is always `False`, because all elements of your list are more lists, and an int is never equal to a list. However, with a numpy.int64, the comparison *broadcasts*. When you compare

```
numpy.int64(31) == [31]
```

`[31]` is converted to a NumPy array, and you get an array of elementwise comparison results, comparing `numpy.int64(31)` to every element of the array, resulting in

```
numpy.array([True])
```

A one-element NumPy boolean array is treated as its single element in an `if` check, so when the list's `in` logic compares `numpy.int64(31)` against `[31]`, it thinks these are equal, and it reports `True` as the result of the `in` check.

Comment: thanks @user2357112, this answers my question why nympy.int64 check went through.